# Lenovo T400 Hangs after Resume from Suspend in Raring Ringtail

Tags: 13.04, suspend, lenovo

I've upgraded from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04 recently and now my system hangs if I resume from Suspend. Any suggestions how to fix this or how to diagnose the problem?

Its a Lenovo T400 Laptop.

**Update:**

The behaviour is slightly different from what I wrote first. After a resume I can still use the system for about 5-30 seconds, before the mouse pointer gradually slows down and the laptop grinds to a total halt.

**Workaround**

A workaround that seems to be working for me if I'm quick enough: If I change to a console window (ctrl + alt + f1) before the mouse pointer hangs, the system runs after a resume.